# Elements that commute with $1$ in the pushout of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra

Tags: ct.category-theory, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Suppose $B$ and $C$ are commutative unital $C^{\ast}$-algebras with $B \subseteq C$ (unital). Let $c$ be an element of $C$ such that $c \ast 1 = 1 \ast c$ in the pushout (in the category of commutative unital $C^{\ast}$-algebras) $C \ast_B C$. Is it valid to conclude that $c$ belongs to $B$?

Comment: In which category are you taking the pushout? The category of (all) C*-algebras and $*$-homomorphisms? If so, I think you'll want to assume that the inclusion $B \subseteq C$ is unital, since otherwise there are trivial counterexamples like $B = 0$ and $c = 1$.

Comment: @TobiasFritz Thanks for your comment! Edited.

Comment: I think the answer is yes, for the following reason. Under Gelfand duality, you're basically asking whether every epimorphism in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces is an [effective epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+epimorphism). The nLab suggests that [in a pretopos, every epimorphism is effective](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+epimorphism#examples) and that [compact Hausdorff spaces form a pretopos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pretopos#examples). However, I have not verified these statements myself.

Comment: I don't speak category language, but if you are asking if $c\ast1=1\ast c$ in the amalgamated free product $C*_BC$ implies $c\in B$, it's true for any unital inclusion of (not necessarily commutative) $\mbox{C}^*$-algebras (although I'm not sure if there is a citable reference for this).

Comment: @TobiasFritz I'm almost seeing it! But I don't get what the condition "$c \in C$ with $c \ast 1 = 1 \ast c$ translates to via Gelfand Duality. Can you explain to me?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Prof. @NarutakaOZAWA! I have the intuition that this is, in fact, true, but I haven't managed to find a proper proof.

Comment: @TobiasFritz You are completely right, if you write this as an answer I will mark it as correct!

Comment: For the record, I write down the proof for general C*-algebras but don't need not the reputation points if Tobias writes his answer.

Comment: Wait. My answer was for the category of general C*-algebras and not for commutative C*-algebras. Unfortunately, I'm not interested in the category of commutative C*-algebras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes: $1 \ast c = c \ast 1$ implies $c \in B$.

---

To see this, let me first translate the statement into fully categorical language. If we restrict to $\|c\| \le 1$ wlog, then the elements $c \in C$ are in bijection with unital $*$-homomorphisms $\mathscr{C}(D) \to C$, where $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is the unit disk; this is precisely the statement of functional calculus.

Thus, we can formulate the original question as follows: if a morphism $\mathscr{C}(D) \to C$ equalizes the two inclusion maps $C \rightrightarrows C \ast_B C$, then does itt factor across $B$? If this property even holds for all objects $A$ in place of $\mathscr{C}(D)$, then this is known as the inclusion $B \hookrightarrow C$ being an [effective monomorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+monomorphism). It is thus enough to show that this is the case.

Equivalently, under Gelfand duality it is enough to show that every epimorphism in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces is effective. Since this category has pullbacks, it is enough to show that every epimorphism is [regular](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+epimorphism). This is well-known to be the case, see e.g. the paper [Algebra $\cap$ Topology = compactness](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016660X71900018?via%3Dihub) of Herrlich and Strecker.

Comment: Thanks, Prof Tobias Fritz! I liked your solution a lot.

Answer (score 6):

*The following is not an answer to the original question for the category of commutative unital $\mbox{C}^*$-algebras, but is an answer to the same question for the category of general unital $\mbox{C}^*$-algebras.*

Given a unital inclusion $B\subset C$, we consider
the universal representation $C \subset B(H)$, i.e.,
$C''\cong C^{**}$ in a standard way.

**Lemma.**
If $c\in C$ commutes with every orthogonal projection $P\in B'$, then $c\in B$.

**Proof.**
The von Neumann algebra $B'$ is generated by orthogonal projections.
Hence by the bicommutant theorem, the assumption implies $c\in B''\cong B^{**}$.
By the Harh-Banach theorem, this implies $c\in B^{**}\cap C = B$ inside $C^{**}$.

Now suppose $c\notin B$ and take $P\in B'$ that does not commute with $c$.
Note that $P\in B'$ means that $K:=PH$ is $B$-invariant.
I will write by $C_i$ the $i$-th copy of $C$ in $C*_BC$.
Let $H_i$ be copies of $H$, but $K\subset H_i$ are identified.
Now $C_i$ acts on $H_i$ with $B$ action on $K$ are identified.

Put $H_1^\circ := H_1 \ominus K$, which is $B$-invariant,
and dilate the representation $B$ on $H_1^\circ$ to
a representation $C_2$ on $H_{12}\supset H_1^\circ$
by the Stinespring dilation theorem. Put $H_{12}^\circ := H_{12}\ominus H_1^\circ$, which is $B$-invariant,  and dilate the representation $B$ on $H_{12}^\circ$ to a representation $C_1$ on $H_{121}\supset H_{12}^\circ$ by the Stinespring dilation theorem. Continue this, and do the same thing for the other side.
Finally, set
\begin{align*}
\tilde{H} &=\cdots\oplus H_{121}^\circ\oplus H_{12}^\circ\oplus H_1^\circ\oplus K \oplus H_{2}^\circ
\oplus H_{21}^\circ\oplus H_{212}^\circ\cdots\\
&=\cdots\oplus\bigl(H_{121}^\circ\oplus H_{12}^\circ\bigr)\oplus\bigl(H_1^\circ\oplus K \bigr)\oplus\bigl(H_{2}^\circ
\oplus H_{21}^\circ\bigr)\oplus H_{212}^\circ\cdots\\
&=\cdots\oplus H_{121}^\circ\oplus\bigl(H_{12}^\circ\oplus H_1^\circ\bigr)\oplus\bigl(K \oplus H_{2}^\circ\bigr)
\oplus\bigl(H_{21}^\circ\oplus H_{212}^\circ\bigr)\cdots.
\end{align*}
Then, $B$ acts on the first line, $C_1$ acts on the second line,
and $C_2$ acts on the third line.
This gives rise to a representation of $C*_BC$ on $\tilde{H}$.
Now one sees that
$\operatorname{ran}((c*1)P) \subset H_1^\circ\oplus K$
and
$\operatorname{ran}((1*c)P) \subset K\oplus H_2^\circ$.
The only way that $(c*1)P=(1*c)P$
is that $c$ leaves $K$ invariant.
The same for $P(c*1)=P(1*c)$.
It follows that $c*1=1*c$ implies $cP=Pc$.

The above proof can be modified to prove the (more general)
fact that the relative Haagerup tensor product is embedded
completely isometrically into the amalgamated free product,
i.e., $B_1\otimes^h_B C_2\subset C_1*_BC_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Prof Ozawa! The case for non-commutative C*algebras is also interesting to me! I still have to assimilate your proof completely. Thanks again.